# Prompt text for JFormattedTextField is not working

Tags: java, user-interface

I wanted to add a text prompt for my JFormattedTextField and I searched it on google on how I could do this. I got a lot of hits for the following code below but when I put it into my code in eclipse it doesn't recognize any of it. Can someone tell me why?

Here are two possible ways to add a text prompt:

```
  PromptSupport.setPrompt("prompt", textComponent);
  TextPrompt p = new TextPrompt("text", textComponent);
```

I got it from the following link:
[How to display a default message in JTextField java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916255/how-to-display-a-default-message-in-jtextfield-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the most probable reasons why eclipse doesn't recognize any of these classes are because they are not a part of the `JDK`.

`PromptSupport` is a part of the [XSwingX](http://code.google.com/p/xswingx/wiki/GettingStarted) library. If you want to use this library for setting PromptText, you will have to download the jar and add it to the build path of the project.

I am not sure whether `TextPrompt` is the class `XSwingX` as well.