# Overlapping JTextField and JLabel

Tags: java, netbeans, jlabel, jtextfield

The one on top is a JLabel with an image. I want the JTextfield inside it.

[image: The one on top is a JLabel with an image. I want the JTextfield inside it.]

I want to overlap a JLabel and JTextField but im have all sort of problems. I am using Netbeans. How can I do this? PLease help.

Comment: Try `AbsoluteLayout` with your `JFrame`.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a watermark, that is text that appears in your text field to prompt a user for input? [Something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805486/adding-a-watermark-to-an-empty-jcombobox)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a JPanel that provides this functionality:

```
public class JTextFieldWithIcon extends JPanel {

    private JTextField jtextfield;
    private ImageIcon image;

    public JTextFieldWithIcon(ImageIcon imgIco, String defaultText) {
        super();
        this.image = imgIco;
        setLayout(null);

        this.jtextfield = new JTextField(defaultText);
        jtextfield.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        jtextfield.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        jtextfield.setBounds(50, 0, 286, 40);
        add(jtextfield);

        JLabel imageLbl = new JLabel();
        imageLbl.setBounds(0, 0, 286, 40);
        imageLbl.setIcon(imgIco);
        add(imageLbl);
    }

    public Icon getIcon() {
        return this.image;
    }

    public JTextField getJTextField() {
        return this.jtextfield;
    }

}
```

The above code produces this:

[image: Result of above code]

An alternative approach is to  arrange the image to the left of the `JTextField`.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JTextFieldWithIcon extends JPanel {


    private JTextField jtextfield;
    private ImageIcon image;

    public JTextFieldWithIcon(ImageIcon imgIco,String defaultText) {
        super();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.jtextfield = new JTextField(defaultText);
        this.image = imgIco;

        JLabel imageLbl = new JLabel();
        imageLbl.setIcon(image);
        add(imageLbl,BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(jtextfield,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public Icon getIcon(){
        return this.image;
    }

    public JTextField getJTextField(){
        return this.jtextfield;
    }

}
```

Note: The `ImageIcon` is not scaled automatically in the above code. You probably want to either pre-scale the `ImageIcon` so that it is the same height as the `JTextField`, or add that logic to the constructor.