# How to change the font of a string in gui and then change it back again to normal

Tags: java, string, user-interface, fonts, textfield

Hello fellow programmers across the world I am currently having a problem with one of my frames in my GUI. I have managed to change the font of my messeges to itallic and the color to grey and i have set my textfield to editable(true). The problem is that when I delete the string in gray and italic and try to write something useful in the textfield, rather that plain font and a color of black for the string it always comes out italic and gray. Is there any way that a string in a text message can change font and color and then then next string you write to have the normal font and black color? Would appreciate any sugggestions at this point. Here is my code:

```
void makeSecondFrame(){
       frame2 = new JFrame("Step one!Vertification!");
       Container contentPane2 = frame2.getContentPane();
       JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Welcome to step 1 of our algorithm, Verification!" + "To varify yourself of owning an account please enter the following:");
       JLabel label3 = new JLabel("First Name:");
       JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Middle Name:");
       JLabel label5 = new JLabel("Surname:");
       JLabel label6 = new JLabel("Account Number:");
       JLabel label7 = new JLabel ("Registration Number:");
       firstName = new TextField("Enter your name here");
       firstName.setForeground(Color.gray);
       firstName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 12));
       firstName.setEditable(true);
       middleName = new TextField("Enter your middle name here");
       middleName.setForeground(Color.gray);
       middleName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 12));
       middleName.setEditable(true);
       surname = new TextField("Enter your surname here");
       surname.setForeground(Color.gray);
       surname.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 12));
       surname.setEditable(true);
       accountNumber = new TextField("Enter your main account number");
       accountNumber.setForeground(Color.gray);
       accountNumber.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 12));
       accountNumber.setEditable(true);
       registrationNumber = new TextField("Enter your registration number");
       registrationNumber.setForeground(Color.gray);
       registrationNumber.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arail", Font.ITALIC, 12));
       registrationNumber.setEditable(true);
       JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));
       p2.add(label2);
       contentPane2.add(p2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
       JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10,1));
       p3.add(label3);
       p3.add(firstName);
       p3.add(label4);
       p3.add(middleName);
       p3.add(label5);
       p3.add(surname);
       p3.add(label7);
       p3.add(registrationNumber);
       p3.add(label6);
       p3.add(accountNumber);
       contentPane2.add(p3, BorderLayout.WEST);
       JButton next = new JButton("Next!");
       next.addActionListener(this);
       JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
       cancel.addActionListener(this);
       JPanel p4 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));
       p4.add(next);
       p4.add(cancel);
       contentPane2.add(p4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
       frame2.pack();
       frame2.setVisible(true);
   }
```

Comment: If you want the font to change you have to change it programmatically the same way you set it.

Comment: What you obviously want is a "input help message". This is not supported by *Swing*, but *JavaFX* supports that. Maybe you have a look at this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to act on an appropriate action on the JTextField. The best I can think of is the `FocusListener.focusGained()`:

```
   firstName = new TextField("Enter your name here");
   firstName.setForeground(Color.gray);
   firstName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 12));
   firstName.setEditable(true);
   firstName.addFocuListener(new FocusAdapter(){
      @Overwrite
      public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
         firstName.setText("");// remove help message, will also remove previously entered text!
         firstName.setFont(new JTextField().getFont()); // reset to default
      }
   }
```

---

> Well that did remove the helper message – Христо Петков

as I mentioned...

> and I want to keep it – Христо Петков

Then you might want to use the other method in the `FocusListener` interface too:

```
      @Overwrite
      public void focusLost(FocusEvent e){
         if(userDidNotEnterTextIn(firstName){ // hopefully you know how to find out...
            firstName.setText("Enter your name here");
         // do formatting again
         }
      }
```

Comment: Well that did remove the helper message and I want to keep it unfortunately so we are getting close but not quite there

Comment: thanks it helped a lot but i dindt use a focus i just did the same thing but with a keyListener and thei what I did to make it work in case anybody else is wondering:

Comment: @ХристоПетков: Use [`DocumentListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) instead.

Comment: @trashgod how do you distinguish in the `DocumentListener` *when* to delete the input help?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: I'm just trying to steer the OP away from `KeyListener`; camickr illustrates using a `DocumentListener` in `TextPrompt`, outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1805667/230513) and cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20578858/230513).